# cast object to string check if valid

Tags: java, object, casting

Im using the following code that the fieldValue can have simple property , there is a way to check before im doing this code if fieldValue is not contain object that cannot be cast to string ?to avoid dump

```
keyVal.put(fieldName, (String) fieldValue);
```

Comment: Is there any class in Java that cannot be casted to String?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (fieldValue instanceof String)
```

Comment: I cannot use ti since field value is type object and can have there either numbers so the if will not success

Comment: @James Berners: By type object, are you talking about `Class` type? If so, then you can use `asSubclass()` function to convert it into String class or use `isAssignableFrom()` to check if its a super-class of String.

Comment: @fge I have tried it I for example I got type object and there is value like 10 and the if is not work

Comment: If by "not work" you mean evaluate to `false` then that is to be expected, since `Integer` cannot be cast to `String`.

Comment: @JamesBerners: if what you need is a string representation of an Object, then my answer might be a fit for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since `String` is a `final` class (and hence cannot have subclasses), I would consider using `getClass` over `instanceof`:

```
if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue.getClass() == String.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fieldValue instanceof String) {

    keyVal.put(fieldName, (String) fieldValue);

}
```

Comment: I cannot use it since the if will not work ,the data fieldValue is type object...